# FTP upload begins and then drops abruptly

Tags: windows-10, ftp, curl, upload, git-bash

I am running the following `curl` command to upload files using git-bash from two Windows 10 machines (Client A and Client B) to a Windows Server (Server X).

```
curl --continue-at - \ 
    -T /path/to/client/source_location/filename.txt \
    ftp://Sftp.domain.name:21/path/to/server/destination_location/filename.txt \
    -u username:password
```

It runs fine from Client A.

For Client B, I see the command execute like [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfHws.gif) and the below `curl` error:

`curl: (55) Send failure: Connection was reset`

for a ~109MB text file. When I check the destination, I see it transfers ~20MB. I tried running the same command for a ~7MB text file hoping it would transfer the whole thing (given size < 20MB). But it transfers ~1.5MB. Client B seems to want to transfer only 20% of large files.

*My question is what can I do to work towards a solution or narrow down the problem further?*

Things to note:

- I know this is not a `curl` issue because I face the same problem using FileZilla.
- This is most likely not Server X because, the same command works from Client A.
- I used `--continue-at -` flag to 'resume upload'. Otherwise, transfers are no more than ~0.7MB.

Comment: Is client A on a different network, and is the server? If so its likely a connection tracking/NAT issue.  If you set up a vpn between your client and the server and FTP across that it can rule out or point towards problems with NAT and FTP.  Something a lot less likely to help, but might be useful is changing between active and passive mode.

Comment: @davidgo thank you for the response. Yes, Client A, Client B and Server X are in 3 different networks. Setting up VPN may not be feasible in my organization. 16 other Clients [C-R] can upload files >~109MB to Server X on a daily basis just like Client A can. Ideal solution would be to make changes in Client B only and not on Server X unless absolutely necessary. Thanks for pointing out the issue might just have to do with NAT. Easy (but expensive) solution would be to upgrade the router. Worried that it might still be hit and miss.

Comment: Are you able to use a different protocol to upload instead? (this can both alleviate the bottleneck using a work-around and highlight performance limitations.  SFTP/SCP, Webdav or using a suitably firewalled  NFS or SMB filesystem might all be work-arounds.

Comment: Some other "hail mary pass" things you might try are setting up your router with a DMZ pointing to your computer (beware that this negates NAT firewall type protections), trying a lower MTU on your outbound interface (try 1476, and if that works, increase gradually to 1500 until it breaks - I'd suggest in increments of 8 bytes).